# Stripe payment link additional params metada are missing on webhook

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I have created stripe payment link,
I have concatenated a clientId to the payment link

[Stripe payment link]?client_id=123

I have created a webhook
And IAM able to see request are coming
But the client id is not part of the metada on payload or on Event

```
String signHeader = request.getHeader("Stripe-Signature"):
Webhook.constructEvent(payload, sigHeader, STRIPE_SIGN_SECRET):
```

Where I can find the client ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL parameter `client_id` doesn't exist on Payment Links. Instead you should use `client_reference_id` as [mentioned here](https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/url-parameters#streamline-reconciliation-with-a-url-parameter).

Then when you receive a `checkout.session.completed` event, the payload will contain a Checkout Session object with the [`client_reference_id`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-client_reference_id) property.